# Keeping specific columns from a data frame

Tags: r

I have tried to extract specific columns from data frame and I have some issues.

I have a data frame of 2874 variables and I define a list of interesting variables like that:

```
outcome <- c("psmdd", "psmci", "psmd", "psds1", "psds2", "neuroticism", "insomnia")
```

I use `mydata[, outcome]` to extract a data frame with only variables in outcome. But, I get this error:

> Error in [.data.frame(mydata, 2, va.names) : undefined columns selected.

Comment: Is it because of this: insominia should be "insomnia" ?

Comment: it seems there is a column name in outcome that is not present in the dataframe. Try  `mydata[, outcome[1]]`, then `mydata[, outcome[2]]`, then ` `mydata[, outcome[3]]`.. `mydata[, outcome[7]]`. Theone that gives you an error should be removed. Lets say the error occurs at 3. Then you do `outcome <- outcome[-3]`

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try.

Comment: Yes! I find where is the errors, it is in my outcome vector. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `dplyr::select()` command it will tell you if a column is missing, e.g.

```
dplyr::select(mydata, outcome)
```

Will give:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `<misspelt column name>` doesn't exist.
```

If that's not your problem, then repost.